# Django order search results by usage in foreign key relation

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have my search results sorted by use in a foreign key relation when searching for one of my Django models.
Example:
Model "Tag" -> Many to Many <- Model "Post"

If I am searching for a tag, I would like to get the query matching tags returned in the order they are used in the relation. This means the most used tag that meets the search criteria first, etc.

Is that possible, if so, how?

I have big problems to adapt the proposed approach to my application, so here some code for clarification:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       ordering = #by number of relations to Post

class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more complete answer based on Alexandr's:

For the sake of the answer, I assume that your `Tag` model has a `name` field to search by.

```
from django.db.models import Count
search_term = 'this is the string you search for'
query = Tag.objects.filter(name__contains=search_term).annotate(post_count=Count('post')).order_by('-post_count')
```

In more detail:
`Tag.objects.filter(name__contains=search_term)` returns a `QuerySet` with `Tag` instances whose `name` contains the expression defined in the variable `search_term` (we assume this comes from the user, who wants to search for tags).

`.annotate(post_count=Count('post')` adds an extra field to the instances that contains the number of relations to `Posts` for that specific instance. You can refer to this in your code in the following way:

```
for tag in query:
    print('This tag is used for', tag.post_count, 'posts')
```

Finally, `.order_by('-post_count')` sets the order to be by post count, in descending order (this is what the `-` denotes).

Answer (score 1):

To order by most used tag, you probably should use something like

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = matching_tags.annotate(used_count=Count('posts'))
queryset = queryset.order_by('-used_count')
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, but I have not managed to adapt the proposal to my project. I added my question in the hope that someone can help with the adaptation.